# Mockito. Dependency I am trying to mock is NULL

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In my class which I am trying to test I have `@Resource` annotated dependency, I am trying to write some tests and want to inject that dependency and my problem is that, after mocking the dependency it's value is `null`

```
private SOAPService soapService;
private WebServiceContext webServiceContext = mock(WebServiceContextImpl.class);

@Before
public void setup(){
    soapService = new SOAPService(webServiceContext);
}

@Test
public void startUploadFileTest(){
    soapService.startUpload("text");
    ......
    /I omitted the remaining code, because I get the NullPointerException/
}
```

NB. My Test Class is annotated with `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`

**EDIT** SoapService Implementation

```
@WebService
public class SOAPService{

        private final static AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();
        private WebServiceContext webServiceContext; 

        public SOAPService(WebServiceContext webServiceContext){
                this.webServiceContext = webServiceContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int startUpload(@WebParam String name) {
            String username = Authentication.getUsername(webServiceContext.getMessageContext());

            try {
                File file = new File(username + "/" + name);
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return id.getAndIncrement();
        }
}

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.example.SOAPService.startUpload(SOAPService.java:97)
    at org.example.services.SOAPServiceTest.startUploadFileTest(SOAPServiceTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: You don't initialize `debtService` in the snippet. Is it the same as `soapService`?

Comment: @Danstahr yes it should've been the same thing

Comment: Is it possible to add your SoapService class along with the stacktrace? Which version of Mockito, JUnit are you using?

Comment: @javahippie I've updated the post

Comment: Can you verify via debugger that webServiceContext is null?

Comment: whenever startUpload method is called the webServiceContext is null

Comment: @javahippie I've edited the implementation can you take the look maybe some ideas

Comment: Please be sure that the code you are posting compiles and represents your real code. You've got a naming conflict between your parameter `String file` and your local `File file`. This won't compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86896/discussion-between-ilia-aptsiauri-and-javahippie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to init your soapService like that:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    soapService = new SOAPService();
    Mockito.initMocks(soapService);
}
```

**EDIT**

With your new code, you also have to mock the static method

```
Authentication.getUsername(...)
```

In order to do that you have to use PowerMockito.

Add before class declaration annotation @PrepareForTest like

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({Authentication.class})
public class MyTest {
   ....
}
```

During preparation of your test mock the call to getUserName like that

```
@Before
public void setup(){
   soapService = new SOAPService(webServiceContext);
   PowerMockito.when(Authentication.getUsername(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("m‌​yVal‌​ue");
}
```

Comment: @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) should take care of initializing the mocks, but yes I have tried it and didn't work

Comment: Ok. I edit my answer. I think you have to annotate your SoapService with @InjectMocks.

Comment: I did it before but got the same result, I made some changed to the code where I am injecting dependency in constructor but I still have the same problem, intercepting the method calls seems not to work

Comment: Can you check if the NPE is on webServiceContext or Authentication.getUsername ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86897/discussion-between-ilia-aptsiauri-and-kuroro).

Comment: Hey, I am glad you found a solution. But could you update your post with the solution from your chat, so that it will help future readers, too?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it, your soapService has no connection to your mocked webServiceContext.

**If you use dependency injection in your classes:**
You should annotate your SOAPService field with `@InjectMocks` so Mockito will know what to do. If you do so, Mockito will instantiate your soapService and Inject the Mocks into it. There will be no need to call a constructor by hand.

**If you do not use dependency injection in your classes:**
You have to set your WebServiceContext into your soapService via setter, this does not happen magically.

Comment: I am using filed injection in my class. I used @InjectMocks annotation but the result is the same

Comment: Did you also remove the manual constructor call in your before method? This will replace your instance with the injected mock.